# Replace _ wrapper with html <i> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get with javascript regex this:

```
> "Who are _you_?" said _the Caterpillar_. 
> -- >
> "Who are <i>you</i>?" said <i>the Caterpillar</i>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
var str = 'Who are _you_?'
var italicized = str.replace(/_(.*?)_/g, '<i>$1</i>');
// => 'Who are <i>you</i>?'
```

`.*` means "any character, 0 or more times," and `?` makes it non-greedy (so that it doesn't keep chomping the `_`s until it gets to the last one).

The `()`s capture the text that you want, and `$1` in the replace string places the captured text back in the string.